# character chain transformation

Tags: c++, character

I have to convert a string containing several letters, some of which have accented vowels, is there a routine to do it automatically, rather than doing it character by character?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you have to transform such letters?

Comment: This depends on many things, one of which is what you mean by *automatically*. Obviously there is no way to process all the characters in a string except by doing something character by character. But perhaps you mean using something like `std::transform`, which although it works character by character, you don't have to write the character by character loop, that's already written for you. Another issue is what kind of transformation you are trying to do.

Comment: I use an SQLite database under Borland, and SQL sorts separate accentuated vowels from others, I thought I would add another field in the table (which contains words and their numbers) to put an non-accented version of the word.

Comment: @user19638201 Well `std::transform` would do that. But you still have to write the code to convert the accented characters, and internally to `std::transform` you are still processing character by character. I'm still not really sure what your goals are, but that's my best suggestion.